# Correct usage of they/those

Tags: word-usage

When you ask someone for certain files, which of the followings is correct?

1. **They** are not uploaded on the website, can you please upload them when you have a chance?
2. **Those** are not uploaded on the website, can you please upload those when you have a chance?

I have always used ***they*** before, but I feel like those is correct. Is either one correct?

Answer (score 1):

**They** is plural of he/she/it. You use **they** to refer to **one** group of things that have already been mentioned in the conversation:

> A: Are Peter and Laura coming?
>   B: Yes, **they** should be here soon. <--***they*** means Peter and Laura

**Those** is the plural of **that**. You generally use **those** in the same way as you use **these**, to refer to **one of two** distinct groups of things.

> A: Can I throw away these newspapers?
>   B: You can take **those**, but not **these**

When you use **those** without a **these**, it suggests that there is some other group, for example:

> Those are not uploaded on the website...

this implies that some other items have already been uploaded to the web site.